# javaScript - multiple inheritance in ES6,

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to inherit class "EventEmitter" and a pre defined class  "Person", here is the code

```
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age; 
    }
    introduces() {
        return `My name is ${this.name}. I am ${this.age} years old.`;
    }
}; 

\\here comes the mixin part

function mix(...mixins) {
    class Mix {}
    for (let mixin of mixins) {
        copyProperties(Mix, mixin);
        copyProperties(Mix.prototype, mixin.prototype);
    }
    return Mix;
}

function copyProperties(target, source) {
    for (let key of Reflect.ownKeys(source)) {  
        if (key !== "constructor" &&  key !== "prototype" && key !== "name") {
            let desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, key);
            Object.defineProperty(target, key, desc);
        }
    }
}
```

I intend to create a new class 'PersonWithEmitter', and still call the constructor like below:

```
class PersonWithEmitter extends mix(Person,EventEmitter){
    constructor(name,age){
        super(name,age)
        \\do something else
    }
```

Here comes the issue, when I create a new instance of 'PersonWithEmitter' like this `let someOne = new PersonWithEmitter("Tom",21)`, will not get what I what, In the new class, I want to use `this.name` and `this.age`, which is still undefined.
So how can I change my code, So the new class can both have its parent's methods and only class "Person"'s constructor?
Pardon me for my broken English.

Comment: **Don't write entirely in bold**.

Comment: Why not used an existing implementation like https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-emitter-mixin

Comment: @loganfsmyth I think this question is more about _why it doesnt work_ than _how to implement this_. Clearly, implementing something like this isn't the issue, it's how the mixin works in JS thats at quesion here...

Comment: Never hurts to confirm.

Comment: @somethinghere since this is my first time use mixin and EventEmitter,I just  cannot figure out the right way to implement this.

Comment: @YuDuan I am curious to see how this works as well, as `mdn` didnt really make it clear how this works, and I had no idea you could actually do this, so yeah, with you on that one (+1)

Comment: The biggest question in my mind now is that if it's possible to do it the way I want, or I just let the class Person inherit the EventEmitter, so It can behave the same

Comment: @loganfsmyth I just glanced at it, I think it's not what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many cases multiple inheritance in JavaScript indicates wrong design decision. It may result in hacky objects that don't behave as they should. The way it is done should always be determined by particular objects. In some cases a shallow copy of own properties is needed, in another the entire prototype chain should be traversed. [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) is often a better choice.

The problem in the code above is that class constructors are not called. `Mix` has empty constructor. This is the reason why `PersonWithEmitter` doesn't work as expected.

Multiple constructor function calls can generally be stacked like:

```
function Foo(...args) {
  let _this = this;
  _this = Bar.apply(_this, args);
  _this = Baz.apply(_this, args);
  return _this;
}
```

This won't work if `Bar` or `Baz` is ES6 class because it contains a mechanism that prevents it from being called without `new`. In this case they should be instantiated:

```
function Foo(...args) {
  copyProperties(this, new Bar(...args));
  copyProperties(this, new Baz(...args));
}
```

Static and prototype properties may also be copied to `Foo` like is shown in code above.

If the case is narrowed down to Node.js `EventEmitter`, it can be handled like a special case. Its implementation is [certain](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v8.3.0/lib/events.js) and stable. It is already known that `EventEmitter` does initialization in constructor, it has a shallow prototype chain and property descriptors. So it likely should be:

```
class Foo extends Bar {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args)
    EventEmitter.call(this);
    // or
    // EventEmitter.init.call(this);
}
copyProperties(Foo.prototype, EventEmitter.prototype);
```

Comment: Thank you, problem solved. The way I see it now, I can do it in two way, First, I can just let class Person inherit EventEmitter, and it did works. Second, I can call EventEmitter in the constructor as you write above.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, in the case with EventEmitter both options are valid.